# How to find an element from this:

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
<ul class="chosen-choices"><li class="search-choice"><span>Nouveau</span><a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="0"></a></li><li class="search-choice"><span>En attente</span><a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="1"></a></li><li class="search-field"><input type="text" value="Choisissez quelques options" class="" autocomplete="off" style="width: 25px;"></li></ul>
<li class="search-choice"><span>Nouveau</span><a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="0"></a></li>
<span>Nouveau</span>
<a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="0"></a>
```

Hello I got this and I want to click on the "`<a class="search-choice-close`"  with selenium in Python.And I tried

```
test = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('chosen-container chosen-container-multi chosen-enable form-select chosen-processed chosen-with-drop chosen-container-active')
for items2 in test:
    test1 = items2.find_element_by_class_name('search-choice-close')
    test1.click()
```

And I cannot find the result.

Comment: inspect <a class="search-choice-close" get the element by Xpath. Use Xpath to click on it.

Comment: while for loop you can store the results into list/dictionary.

Comment: _I cannot find the result_  What does this mean, exactly?  Does your code produce an error, or unwanted results, or no results at all?

Comment: Thanks Pygirl it works by xpath.

Comment: I want to remove a value from a list and now it works by  xpath, thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone will have the same problem like me it works like this:`test = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="edit_field_statut_mandat_value_chosen"]/ul/li[3]/a')
test.click()`

Comment: `click()` returns _void_ hence **test** will be always **NULL**